# Fill a cirle with an image without distortion

Tags: html, css

I have a site where users can upload photographs of unknown dimensions.
I'm trying to find out how to make the images circles of a fixed size. I can create the circles and me the images round but i can't figure out how to prevent the images from distorting when put in a circle. Is there a way to fill a fixed sized circle with any image witout distorting the image (centered preferably)? I've made a fiddle here. Many thanks.

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MUnoV4capRk/600x300" alt="" id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: The image is squashed. I wan to keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `object-fit`

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MUnoV4capRk/600x300" alt="" id="circle"></div>
```

For more information read [`object-fit` in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of the image and the container are different. Image is bigger then the containing element and that is why, image looks distorted.

You should use, `object-fit: cover`

```css
#circle {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MUnoV4capRk/600x300" alt="" id="circle"></div>
```

Read more about `object-fit` property here: [object-fit css](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use it as background:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/MUnoV4capRk/600x300);"></div>
```